# error in publishing an Eigen::Matrix using rostopic

Tags: eigen, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this 2D Eigen Matrix called map and I wish to publish it using a rostopic but it gives some unkown error. Here is my code.

```
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<Eigen::MatrixXd>("topic_map_info", 1000);    
  ros::Rate loop_rate(0.1);    
  MatrixXd map = MatrixXd::Random(10,10);

  while (ros::ok())
  {  
    chatter_pub.publish(map);    
    ros::spinOnce();    
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
```

below is part of the error:

In static member function ‘static const char* ros::message_traits::MD5Sum::value(const M&) [with M = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]’:
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:255:104:   instantiated from ‘const char* ros::message_traits::md5sum(const M&) [with M = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]’
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/publisher.h:112:7:   instantiated from ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>]’
/home/khan/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/lawn_mover/src/node_map.cpp:98:28:   instantiated from here
/opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/message_traits.h:126:34: error: ‘const class Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>’ has no member named ‘__getMD5Sum’

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59753/error-in-publishing-an-eigen::matrix-using-rostopic/) by [Mudassir Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4582/mudassir-khan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot publish arbitrary C++ objects to ROS topics, but only those for which a msg definition has been generated. See the [tutorials on msg/srv](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv). Some conversions between Eigen and corresponding msg types are available in the [eigen_conversions](http://ros.org/wiki/eigen_conversions) package. See also the [code API](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/eigen_conversions/html/eigen__msg_8h_source.html). Also included is a conversion from Eigen Matrix to Float64MultiArray (but not the other way around for some reason).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mudassir Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4582/mudassir-khan/) on 2013-04-04**:
thank you, I converted Eigen::Matrix to std_msgs::Float64MultiArray and published it